# Change hald data set in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pca, eigenvector

I want to use `pca` function in **matlab**, but from another directory.how to load that data set to run this function? e.g load image data set from a folder.

```
load hald
coeff = pca(ingredients)
```

Answer (score 1):

`load` can take an absolute or a relative path to the filename you want to load. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html#btm0etn-1-filename) for more options.